# Javascript hide/show on click not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a drop-down list using Html and Javascript, but it is not working for some reason, despite watching every video on Youtube. Here's the code I'm using:
HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="dropdownbtn" onclick="dropdown()">Courses &#9662</button>
    <div id="dropdown-items">
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="li">button!!</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="li">button!!</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="li">button!!</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="li">button!!</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var flag = 0;
function dropdown() {

    if (flag==0) {
        document.getElementById("dropdown-items").style.display = "none";
        flag=1;
    } 

    if (flag==1) {
        document.getElementById("dropdown-items").style.display = "block";
        flag=0;
    }
}
```

I set the display to none in `css` also. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just step through your code. What happens when you click on the button? Will the first `if` block be executed? If so, what is the value of `flag` after leaving the `if` block? As the execution won't stop we will get to the next `if` block. Will this be executed (remember the current value of `flag`)?

Answer (score 1):

it's actually working but you have to place else if because in if condition you change the flag with 1 and also second condition becomes true

```
var flag = 0;

function dropdown() {

    if (flag==0) {

        document.getElementById("dropdown-items").style.display = "none";

        flag=1;
    } 
    else if (flag==1) {

        document.getElementById("dropdown-items").style.display = "block";

        flag=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the dropdown menu is now working

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution, use ternary operators:

```
document.getElementById("dropdown-items").style.display = flag === 0 ? 'none' : ' block'
```

Comment: Your solution is missing the "toggle" part.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use toggleclass here?

```
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button id="dropdownbtn" onclick="dropdown()">Courses &#9662</button>
    <div id="dropdown-items">
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="li">button!!</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="li">button!!</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="li">button!!</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#" class="li">button!!</a></li>
    </div>
    </div>
```

add css like

```
#dropdown-items {
 display: none;
}

.toggleShow {
  display: block;
}
```

In your script

```
<script>
function dropdown() {
   var element = document.getElementById("dropdown-items");
   element.classList.toggle("toggleShow");
}
</script>
```